# How can I correct a typo within a column in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, error-correction

Newbie here.

I am attempting to clean a dataset in R and I came across a zip code that is 9306 instead of 93060.
I googled and read a number of tutorials but none of them updated the data frame. There are over 2,000 observations in this dataset.
I already changed the data type of the zip code column from numerical to characters.

It sounds like this is supposed to work? The dataset is clean_transport_2022, Project_Zip is the zip code list.
`gsub('9306' '93060', clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip)`

I did see that there is a package that can be installed specifically for working with zip codes but for my purposes I really just need to substitute that one bit of data.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should probably do `gsub('^9306$' '93060', clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip)` instead since what you have would change 93061 to 930601 or 
`clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip[clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip %in% '9306'] <- '93060'`

Comment: That kind of "typo" happens when you read in a file and the column is all "digits", so `read.csv` or `read_xlsx` or whatever assumes that it should be an integer column. It is far better to read it in correctly the first time, using `colClasses=` or whatever mechanism provided by the function, so that you don't inadvertently missing one such "typo" in your data.

Comment: @rawr I think your two points (over-eager regex and using strict equality/set-membership) are a far better fix to the damaged data. Post as an answer?

Comment: Thank you @rawr! I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: @r2evans I am a little confused about your answer because I wasn't the one who caused the zip code to be inputted incorrectly and I didn't miss the error because I found it. Maybe I just misunderstood your comment? Anyway, thank you for your comment.

Comment: My comment is that often zip codes are all numeric digits, and most data-reading functions (e.g., `read.table`, `read.csv`, `readr:;read_csv`, `data.table::fread`) will see a column of all digits as an _integer_ column. It's not that a human is a problem (though if it's a typo, then yes it's the human), it's that just reading in the file many times will drop all leading zeroes.

Comment: @r2evans that's why I changed the data type to characters. Maybe I am still misunderstanding

Comment: As far as I know, you are converting to characters after reading in from the file. If you do `dat <- read.csv("file.csv")` and then `dat$zip <- as.character(dat$zip)`, you're not fixing the problem at all. The only way to fix having `read*("file.csv")` read it in correctly the first time is to provide arguments to the reading function that specify the class, such as `read.csv("file.csv", colClasses="character")` or similar. I don't know how you're working because we see no code. It seems I'm pushing up a rope, however, so I'll back off and not presume what you might be doing with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your gsub code does indeed substitute 9306 with 93060; however, as you are new to R I'm going to guess you made a mistake almost everyone starting out with R makes and forgot to assign the result to the data.

That is, you forgot to do

```r
clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip <- gsub('9306' '93060', clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip)
# ^^^^^^^ This part ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you just wrote the RHS of the above assignment operation, you asked R to take the contents `Project_Zip` column, substitute 9306 with 93060, and then return this new object (without modifying the original data frame)

I note you changed the column from numeric to character. This is fair enough if you're using `gsub` however it's not necessary for this particular task. If you leave your column as numeric, you can simply use `ifelse`

```r
clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip <- ifelse(clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip == 9306, 93060, clean_transport_2022$Project_Zip)
```

This solution would be recommended as your gsub solution may incorrectly modify correct zip codes. For example, it would change `93060` to `930600`.

Comment: I believe my last sentence covers that?

Comment: I did actually have that part. I thought about including it in my post but then thought it would be a given? Lol. I don't know what's obvious yet.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about ifelse! I'll try that tomorrow.